# How to cancel "Add Content" for in-app purchases in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I unintentionally clicked "**Add Content**" ...
[image]

... and now I can't test my in-app purchase in sandbox environment !!! WT>#@*UDOKDOENUB...
[image]

How can I cancel this add content. I thought I have to create a fake package and get the Application Loader app (~80MB), upload it and then reject it. Like when you press "**Ready to upload Binary**" button and then you can't go back until you submit and reject it. But that's too much work. There should be a simple way for in-app purchase. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In **iTunes Connect**, go to your app > Manage In-App Purchases > Select your problem in-app purchase in the table. Then down in the middle in the **In-App Purchase Details - New Version** section header. There are `Edit` and `Delete` buttons. Click `Delete` and then confirm the deletion should remove your `Waiting for Upload` state and fix it. It's very small to be missed ;)

PS. After deleting the page will give you an error and you have to go to the main page. Don't worry, Come back to this in-app purchase page and you will see it's all working.

[image]

Comment: @Namo In case you didn't know. When you post a new question, Stackoverflow has this `Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style` checkbox at the bottom. Try that! ;)